# Typing a link in comments displayed with http prefix

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks

Is there a way to type in a link in the comments but while keeping the "http://" prefix visible?

Eg. when I type in `http://10.0.0.10/wp/` it's converted to `10.0.0.10/wp/` in comments. I'd like it to be displayed just as I typed it, or at least I need some way to make it look like the original...

Comment: [http://10.0.0.10/wp/](http://10.0.0.10/wp/) See my answer below on how to do this

Comment: The proposed answers are certainly viable workarounds.

I submit that the original default behavior is still suboptimal. There's no advantage to removing the "http://" prefix from the displayed text, and doing so has the potential to cause needless confusion. I'd suggest that [`http://10.0.0.10/wp/`](http://10.0.0.10/wp/) would be a better default behavior than [10.0.0.10/wp/](http://10.0.0.10/wp/). Low-priority wishlist item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the link syntax:

```
[Link with HTTP](Address)
[http://10.0.0.10/wp/](http://10.0.0.10/wp/)
```

This will keep the http:// part of the URL in your comment.

Comment: Great, makes perfect sense and I was thinking about how to do this for 10 minutes before asking...

Answer (score 3):

If the link appearing as a link (something you can click on) is not important, you can simply wrap it in back ticks:

```
`http://10.0.0.10/wp/`
```

which appears as such:`http://10.0.0.10/wp/`